# How to open .crash_symbolicated

Tags: ios, crash, app-store-connect

Apple did reject an app with description

> 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness

And only attach files:
[Download](https://yadi.sk/d/4dcaR76f3SnDfr)

How to open and read the **.crash_symbolicated** files?